# How much time passed in Dragon Ball Super between the Resurrection of F saga and the Universal Tournament saga?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super we see a huge boost in power of Piccolo, who jumped from

> Being weaker than Super Saiyan Gohan in the Resurrection of F saga, to be stronger than SSJ2 Gohan in the Universal Tournament saga.

This doesn't make much sense unless a decent amount of time passed between the arcs and he did some special training or something. Therefore, my question is, how much time passed in Dragon Ball Super between the Resurrection of F saga and the Universal Tournament saga?

Comment: Piccolo may have used *Hyperbolic time chamber* for training purpose

Comment: yeah, we have to imagine that. This isnt new. Dragon Ball not caring much about continuity and fans having to fill in the plotholes. The problem is many times later, the authors dont take in consideration fans fillers explanation and fell in new plotholes again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly a year.

According to http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Timeline

Resurrection F happens in Aug 779, and Tournament of power occurs in December 780